# Use sed to replace line if pattern is on next line

Tags: sed

How do I get `sed` to replace previous line? I only came across examples of `delete`, `insert` lines, but what I actually need is that I only make substitution to current line if a condition on *following* line is met.

My sample file is like this

```
$ /bin/cat test
Cygwin
Cygwin is a cool emulator for Linux on Windows.

Unix
Maybe
the coolest environment?

Linux
Is also one of the best environments
Solaris
Why did Sun feel copying Java into Unix would matter?

AIX
Unknown
```

The output I expect is as below. Prepend `:::` to strings having max 25 chars but only if the string on *next* line is longer than 25 chars. Thus, the line having `Unix`, `AIX` below should not get prepended with `:::`, but others would.

```
$ # See detailed sed expression in my answer below
:::Cygwin
Cygwin is a cool emulator for Linux on Windows.
Unix
Maybe
the coolest environment?
:::Linux
Is also one of the best environments
:::Solaris
Why did Sun feel copying Java into Unix would matter?
AIX
Unknown
```

What `sed` expression can help me do this?

I am inclined to use only `sed` since this is a part of some other script that has other `sed` expressions going on, so I do *not* want to deviate if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one `sed` expression that gives me the output I desire,

`/bin/sed -rne '/^\s*$/{d;};{p;}' test | /bin/sed -rne  '/(^.{5,26}$)/{$p;h;n;/^.{5,26}$/{x;p;x;p;D;};{x;s/(^.*$)/:::\1/;p;x;p;D;}};{$p;h;p;}'`

Specifically, below two `sed` expressions are piped together above,

```
/bin/sed -rne '/^\s*$/{d;};{p;}' test 
# Remove any empty-lines (optionally containing spaces)

/bin/sed -rne  '/(^.{5,26}$)/{$p;h;n;/^.{5,26}$/{x;p;x;p;D;};{x;s/(^.*$)/:::\1/;p;x;p;D;}};{$p;h;p;}'
# This is the killer sed expression I came up with hunting around with my limited knowledge

# The detailed breakdown of this expression is as below,
/(^.{5,26}$)/ # Get a string of characters atleast 5 chars to max 26 chars
{
 $p; # Print if it's already on last line (since -n is in effect)
 h; # Save it to hold space
 n; # Get the next line into pattern space
  /^.{5,26}$/ # Check if pattern space (i.e. next line) also has min 5, max 26 chars
    { # if above condition passed, execute inside here
      x; # Swap pattern with hold space; i.e. Get current line back
      p; # Print it (i.e. the first line)
      x; # Swap again; to get back next line
      p; # Print it (i.e. the second line)
      D; # Stop cycle here, and process the next line in the input file
    };
    { # else block for above if-condition
      x; # Swap pattern with hold space; i.e. Get current line back
      s/(^.*$)/:::\1/; # Append ::: in front of line
      p; # Print it (i.e. the first line)
      x; # Swap again; to get back next line
      p; # Print it (i.e. the second line)
      D; # Stop cycle here, and process the next line in the input file
     } # End processing next line
  } # End if match
{ # Current line is longer than max 26 chars,
  $p; # Print if it's already on last line (since -n is in effect)
  h; # Remember it in hold space
  p; # Print it (i.e. the current line)
}
```

With above explanation, I am able to achieve what I need.

But I still not confident if this could not be written or explained in a concise, or perhaps better way?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple in `awk` if you get tired of trying to use the hammer of `sed` on this particular screw :-)

```
awk '{x[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(length(x[i])<26 && length(x[i+1])>25)printf ":::";print x[i]}}' file
```

Save all the lines in array `x[]`. At the end, go through the lines printing them but prefixing ones that meet your conditions with `:::`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;/^.{1,25}\n.{26,}$/s/^/:::/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl One-Liner from Command-Line**

This perl one-liner will do it (tested just now):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^([^\n]{1,25}$)(?=\n[^\n]{25,}$)/:::$1/smg' yourfile
```